# Deploy Parse-Server

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I deployed Parse-Server-exemple to Heroku using thee Deploy button, and everything is working fine. (up to the fact that there are some bugs)

But the Parse-Server(https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)is being updated more frequently and now has lower bugs.

How to deploy Parse-Server on Heroku ?? or at least how to update the server running on my existing Heroku app ?? I can't find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Parse-server is the nodejs package. you can remove this line [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example/blob/master/package.json#L15) and you can remove the `node_modules` from `.gitignore`, then you need to download the "Parse Server" to your `node_modles` folder and deploy it. but it will be easy if you try to use some service like [www.parseground.com](http://parseground.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your starting point should be reading up on how to [deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) nodejs apps on heroku. Parse Server is just another npm module. Contrary to @pivanov's answer you should preferably keep `node_modules` in gitignore and let heroku install the npm packages including Parse Server. This is what heroku recommends in their [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits).

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your parse-apps by running the falling command using the heroku work belt

$ heroku login

$ heroku git:clone -a

Heroku at this point automatically create a git branch 'master' that you can commit to.
You can now make changes to your parse server version depending in the available version.
Current version i think is 2.1.4
"parse-server": "^2.1.4",

You can now commit and push changes to the master branch created.

$ git add .

$ git commit -am "make it better"

$ git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
npm update
```

it will update the parse server if you have used "*" as its version in your package.json file.